# Android .apk build fail with Gradle during aapt PNG file handling

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

I'm seen that people are already facing issues with Gradle while compiling an Android, but no one seems to face a specific issue which occurs from time to time while Gradle is running an aapt command supposed to handle PNG files.

My environment :

- Linux Ubuntu 2009-04
- JVM v1.7.0_65
- Gradle v1.11
- Android Build Tools v19.1.0
- Compilation targeting Android API level 19

From time to time, approximatively every 3 build, the Gradle .apk generation fails while it is handling the PNG files that should be shipped in the final .apk.

The command which fails is the following:

```
/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
```

which causes the Gradle build to fail with the following exception (the Gradle build is launched by an Ant script, but running it directly causes the same issue), which results in a 137 error code:

```
 [exec] Error: Failed to run command:
 [exec]     /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
 [exec] Error Code:
 [exec]     137
 [exec] 
 [exec] :myProject:mergemyFlavorReleaseResources FAILED
 [exec] 
 [exec] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 [exec] 
 [exec] * What went wrong:
 [exec] Execution failed for task ':myProject:mergemyFlavorReleaseResources'.
 [exec] > Error: Failed to run command:
 [exec]     /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
 [exec]   Error Code:
 [exec]     137
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] * Try:
 [exec] Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 [exec] 
 [exec] * Exception is:
 [exec] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':myProject:mergemyFlavorReleaseResources'.
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
 [exec] Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: Failed to run command:
 [exec]     /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
 [exec] Error Code:
 [exec]     137
 [exec] 
 [exec]     at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:96)
 [exec]     at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:70)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:236)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:223)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
 [exec]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
 [exec]     ... 43 more
 [exec] Caused by: Error: Failed to run command:
 [exec]     /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
 [exec] Error Code:
 [exec]     137
 [exec] 
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:53)
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:111)
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:249)
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:25)
 [exec]     at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:89)
 [exec]     ... 53 more
 [exec] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
 [exec]     /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
 [exec] Error Code:
 [exec]     137
 [exec] 
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:98)
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.internal.AaptCruncher.crunchPng(AaptCruncher.java:58)
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:185)
 [exec]     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:136)
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] BUILD FAILED
```

Once the issue occurs, if I run the failing command, i.e.

```
/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt s -i /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/src/main/res/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png -o /home/opt/buildAgent/work/bb4757955823a092/myProject/build/res/all/myFlavor/release/drawable-sw600dp-hdpi/ic_under_18.png
```

I was not able to make it fail. This issue also occurs with the Android Build Tools v19.0.3. I need to mention that no other build is being run at the same time, because I was suspecting in the first place that the problem what due to a concurrent access (which, according to me, is not very likely to be the root cause).

I'm a bit despaired, because the same build with the exact same conditions (the Gradle build is run with a 'clean' task at the start), sometimes succeeds, sometimes fails.

Does anyone (Xavier Ducrochet?) have a clue or a work-around idea, please? Please, tell me if I'm not clear enough, or if important information is missing.

Thank you for your time and help. Regards.

Eventually the following Gradle is executed:

```
/opt/gradle-1.11/bin/gradle --stacktrace clean myRelease
```

Here is an excerpt of my gradle.build file, which is quite heavy and I cannot make it public:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript
{
  repositories
  {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies
  {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-nexus-plugin:0.7'
  }
}

android
{
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

  defaultConfig
  {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
  }
}
```

I hope that helps understanding the weird issue. I'm really wondering whether the issue does not come directly from aapt…

Comment: @Joseph : I've added some excerpt of my Gradle script.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try execute a clean task before invoke a Gradle generation from Ant?, and please if you can provide a build.gradle files content. Why you are still using Ant, when you can use Gradle?